# Migrate a VB Project included in Excel Sheet to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

I am trying to find a proper way to migrate a VB project within an Excel Sheet to C#. Migration will not change most of the code apart from the DB calls because it will use a new DB Structure.

Basically the Project makes several DB calls, performs some calculations and fills some pre-created Excel templates with the data retrieved/handled.

I guess ,the quick way to keep sleeping at night and use these Excel Sheets in the new aplication is to change the VB queries only and update the Excel files to a new version.

However, we want to find a way to migrate the project to C# and perhaps use it in the future in Online Excel Sheets. Here is where I get lost. It seems a way to do it could be with  Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO ) but we have a Community version and they are included in the professional or Ultimate ones, is that correct? Are there any other ways to migrate such a project?

Thanks and regards

Comment: There is no drag and drop / easy way to do this.  You will need a C# developer who understands Excel VBA to properly code this.  If there was an easy point and click way to do this, my company would go out of business.  This is literally what we do every day.

Comment: If this has to run in Excel Online then you can't use C# or VSTO - you need to use the Office JS APIs (JS = JavaScript). Those add-ins run across all platforms (desktop, windows, mac, on-line, iPad versions...) As far as the VSTO templates go, I believe they're part of the "Community" version(s) of VIsual Studio...

Comment: Sorry I meant Visual Studio Community , just found out VSTO is apparently included and.. to migrate the code I will have to create a new project in c#.  The online Sheet part .. can wait at the moment :)  Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I've had to convert a few VB.NET projects to C# before. The following link will usually do a good job.  http://converter.telerik.com/?utm_medium=product&utm_source=converter&utm_campaign=verb